# MySQL procedure gone wrong

Tags: mysql, procedure

I have a MySQL database in which I have the following rows (by exemple) created by default (id, task and case may be different but the current value is always **1**)

[....id](/questions/tagged/....id)[task](/questions/tagged/task)[case](/questions/tagged/case)[user](/questions/tagged/user)[............date](/questions/tagged/............date)[current](/questions/tagged/current)
[238](/questions/tagged/238)[......3](/questions/tagged/......3)[1001](/questions/tagged/1001)[.....0](/questions/tagged/.....0)[..............null](/questions/tagged/..............null)[..........1](/questions/tagged/..........1)
[239](/questions/tagged/239)[......4](/questions/tagged/......4)[1001](/questions/tagged/1001)[.....0](/questions/tagged/.....0)[..............null](/questions/tagged/..............null)[..........1](/questions/tagged/..........1)

I have to randomly create rows like this with insert statement (new rows). As you can see a date is filled and de current equal **0**

[....id](/questions/tagged/....id)[task](/questions/tagged/task)[case](/questions/tagged/case)[user](/questions/tagged/user)[............date](/questions/tagged/............date)[current](/questions/tagged/current)
[240](/questions/tagged/240)[......5](/questions/tagged/......5)[1001](/questions/tagged/1001)[.....1](/questions/tagged/.....1)[2015.04.03](/questions/tagged/2015.04.03)[..........0](/questions/tagged/..........0)
[241](/questions/tagged/241)[......2](/questions/tagged/......2)[1002](/questions/tagged/1002)[.....1](/questions/tagged/.....1)[2015.04.03](/questions/tagged/2015.04.03)[..........0](/questions/tagged/..........0)

When I come across one of the lines created by default I want to use an update instead of an insert statement.

So I created the following procedure in MySQL

```
DELIMITER //
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS FillProgress//
CREATE PROCEDURE FillProgress ( get_case INT(10),get_task INT(10), get_user INT(10) )

BEGIN

   DECLARE test tinyint(1);

   SET test = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM progress WHERE case_id = get_case AND task_id = get_task);

   IF test = 1 THEN 
        UPDATE progress SET current = 0, date = NOW(), user_id = get_user WHERE task_id = get_id AND case_id = get_case;
   ELSE 
        INSERT INTO progress(task_id,case_id,user_id,date,current) VALUES (get_task,get_case,get_user,NOW(),0);
   END IF;

END; //

DELIMITER ;
```

I use count to see if a already have a row with the same case and task. If it's true (test=1) I use **UPDATE**, otherwise and use **INSERT**.

If I test with the following row already wrote in the database

[....id](/questions/tagged/....id)[task](/questions/tagged/task)[case](/questions/tagged/case)[user](/questions/tagged/user)[date](/questions/tagged/date)[current](/questions/tagged/current)
[241](/questions/tagged/241)[......4](/questions/tagged/......4)[1001](/questions/tagged/1001)[.....0](/questions/tagged/.....0)[..null](/questions/tagged/..null)[..........1](/questions/tagged/..........1)

I use `CALL FillProgress(1001,4,1);`

The row is not updated, but I do not have any error message.

```
11:38:02    CALL FillProgress(1001,4,1) 0 row(s) affected   0.000 sec
```

And if I manually use my update query

```
UPDATE progress SET current = 0, date = NOW(), user_id = 1 WHERE task_id = 4 AND case_id = 1001;
```

It works like a charm.

The insert query  also works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UPDATE query within the procedure has a "WHERE task_id = get_id" clause, however I don't see get_id being defined in the procedure; there is a "get_task" parameter for the stored procedure, though.